# hook_node_info is not adding content type to my list

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks

I'm trying to add a new content type from within a module, and I have pretty much borrowed from the ubercart product kit module, since I want to use that as a base for this new type:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_node_info().
*
* @return Node type information for flexible product bundles.
*/
function amh_shop_bundles_node_info() {
    return array(
        'amh_shop_flexi_bundle' => array(
            'name' => t('Flexible Product Bundle'),
            'module' => 'amh_shop_bundles',
            'description' => t('This node represents a flexible bundle package that allows customers to mix and match products and get discounts.'),
            'title_label' => t('Name'),
            'body_label' => t('Description'),
        ),
    );
}
```

But, this new content type isn't being listed in my content types list with the others. I know that the module is loading correctly, as I also created a function amh_shop_bundles_perm() to list permissions, and they are being included in the user permissions listing as expected.

Have I missed something? (Well, most likely, yes). The [Drupal documentation](http://drupal.org/node/231019) says it should really be that easy though.

Update:

I found a comment which provided a test for if the content type is properly generated - by accessing /admin/content/node-type/amh-shop-flexi-bundle

This worked - but the content type is still not listed with the others.

Update 2:

Since I could access a blank node form at /node/add/amh-shop-flexi-bundle I figured I could move on with implementing other hooks - and discovered that you need to implement hook_form() to list the content type.

Comment: So is your problem solved with implementing hook_form()? Then please write your solution in a separate answer, and accept your own answer. Thanks.

Comment: fair point - i'll do that - but it'll have to be tomorrow when I have the code in front of me to reference.

Comment: sorry - it looks like this code was removed a long while ago as the module was no longer needed, and I'm having a hard time finding it in the repository.

Comment: :( But in your "Update 2", there's a possible short answer - if that's correct.

Comment: I'd have to try from scratch again... but I don't really have the time, sorry - you could give it a go?

Comment: maybe I'll try to spend some time to do that a little bit later :) It seems like it's just about creating a content type in the appropriate way, and letting it be correctly displayed among other content types. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The tip to implement hook_form() did the trick for me!

I added just these lines, and baam:

```
function hook_form(){
  $form = array();
  return $form;
}
```